# Transform rectangular region to region bounded by $y=1$ and $y=x^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I found [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121014191242AAx5ez5) nice answer:

But I am trying to find a way to map a rectangular region in the $uv$-plane onto the region bounded by $y=1$ and $y=x^2$ in the $xy$-plane.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:(-1,1)\times (0,1) \to \mathbb{D} ,$ $f(u,v) =(u\sqrt{v}, v).$

Comment: Two questions: 1) How did you figure this out? 2) I don't think it is correct as I believe it maps the region $(-1,1)\times(0,1)$ into the region $(-1,1)\times(0,1)$ minus the region bounded by the curves $y=1$ and $y=x^2$.

Comment: If you fix $v$ then $u$ varies between the curves $u=-\sqrt{v} $ and $u=\sqrt{v} .$

Comment: This answer appears to be correct. I'm sorry, I'm just not seeing how you did this so quickly and easily.

Comment: OK, I do see that if you fix $v$ then $u$ varies between $u=-\sqrt v$ and $u=\sqrt v$, but why does that make you pick $x=u\sqrt v$ and $y=v$?